# How to avoid the model to change position on walk animation?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I downloaded Raw Mocap Data Asset from Unity from Unity Asset Store

I load any walk animation to my animator and it works fine

the issue is the animation itself changes the model position, I don't want that, I want to move by my own mechanism.

Is there anyway to disable the animation from changing position?

Answer (score 0):

Turn off Root Animation on your animator. Then it will not automatically move.

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RootMotion.html

It is enabled by default.

Uncheckmark here:

[image]